# fatal: pathspec 'file-name' did not match any files. file name is not a path

Tags: git, github

I typed on the command line `$sudo service postgresql restart` before working on my branch and when I made a commit git saved it as a new file called "udo service postgresql restart". This file doesn't have a path, it's the same command I typed.

So I tried :

```
git reset HEAD udo service postgresql restart
```

And tried:

```
git rm udo service postgresql restart
```

Got this error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'udo' did not match any files
```

Also tried:

```
git checkout sudo service postgresql restart
```

got this error:

````
error: pathspec 'service' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'postgresql' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'restart' did not match any file(s) known to git.```
````

Comment: Was this file ever part of a commit? Or did you just create a file by mistake and now you're trying to remove it?

Comment: Try use quotes git checkout "udo service postgresql restart"

Comment: @Mureinik for some reason when I typed the postgresql command git staged it as a new file so I had to use `git rm --cached "file name"` and then `git clean -f`

Comment: Looks like something (not Git, which doesn't do this) treated `$s` as a symbol and replaced it with an empty string, leaving `udo service postgresql restart` as the remaining text string ... then interpreted that whole thing as a file name. Later, attempts to pass `udo service postgresql restart` as a string to Git broke it up at spaces the way one would expect, so Git is looking for four separate files with those four names.

Answer (score 1):

Few options:

1. If this file was not committed and not part of your project, simply delete it.
2. If you have a file name with spaces you need to wrap the name with `"` (double quotes)
3. If this file was added to the staging area and you wish to remove it:

   ```sh
   git rm --cached "udo service postgresql restart"
   ```
4. `git restore`
   If you are using the latest version of git (>2.25) you can use the `git restore` command

   [image]

Comment: thank you @CodeWizard I did `git rm --cached "udo service postgresql restart"` and then `git clean -f`